# MySQL DB for exam (test quizzes) query for points

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB where I have stored a table with user information, a table with test (answers and points) and a table with user's answers for each question. Each question is worth in total 1 point and could have one or more correct answers. If all of the answers are correct, and the user check just one, he will receive just 0.25 points. 
I want to make a query to check total points for each user, but I don't find a good method.

User table:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------------+------------+--------+
| userID | first_name | last_name | email             | password   | points |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------------+------------+--------+
|      1 | Jhon       | Jhonny    | jhon@yahoo.com    | secretPass |      0 |
|      2 | Dan        | Dan       | dan@yahoo.com     | 1234       |      0 |
|      3 | Dick       | Pop       | dd@yahoo.com      | 123456     |      0 |
|      4 | Mihaela    | Micky     | mihaela@yahoo.com | pass12     |      0 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------------+------------+--------+
```

Question table:
(1 means that answer is good - we can have multiple correct answers)

```
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+---+---+---+---+
| questionID | question                                         | a | b | c | d |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+---+---+---+---+
|          1 | which of these are colors?                       | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|          2 | which of these are fruits?                       | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|          3 | which of these are programming language?         | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|          4 | What is IPv6?                                    | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+---+---+---+---+
```

User's answer table:(1 means the user choose that answer but may be inccorect )

```
+------------+--------+---+---+---+---+
| questionID | userID | a | b | c | d |
+------------+--------+---+---+---+---+
|          1 |      1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|          2 |      1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|          1 |      3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|          1 |      4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|          3 |      1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|          4 |      1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|          1 |      2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|          2 |      2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
|          3 |      2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|          4 |      2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
|          2 |      3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|          3 |      3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|          4 |      3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|          2 |      4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|          3 |      4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|          4 |      4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+------------+--------+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I surmise you mean 1 of 5 answers correct = 0.2 points (i.e. 20% of 1), not 0.25?

Comment: And it's not really clear where your problem is. You certainly know that you should join questions and answers. You also know how to compare values and you probably know how to aggregate data per user. So where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  a.*,
  u.name,
  q.*,
  # (a.a & q.a) + (a.b & q.b) + (a.c & q.c) + (a.d & q.d) userCorrects,
  # (a.a + a.b + a.c + a.d) questionCorrects,
  ((a.a & q.a) + (a.b & q.b) + (a.c & q.c) + (a.d & q.d)) / (a.a + a.b + a.c + a.d) as userGrade
FROM
 answer a
    INNER JOIN
 user u ON a.userID = u.id
    INNER JOIN
 question q ON a.questionID = q.id
```

Comment: Thanks, i like it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd join questions and answers and add up correct answers. The formula per answer is simply: number of correct answers divided by 5. You'd GROUP BY user ID and SUM to get results per user.

```
select u.userid, u.first_name, u.last_name, counted.points
from
(
  select
    a.userid,
    sum(((a.a = q.a) + (a.b = q.b) + (a.c = q.c) + (a.d = q.d) + (a.e = q.e)) / 5)
      as points
  from question q
  join answer a on a.questionid = q.questionid
  group by a.userid
) counted
join users u on u.userid = counted.userid;
```

In MySQL `true = 1` and `false = 0`, so `(a.a = q.a)` is 1 when correct and 0 when wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question...!!!

I think this query will help you with all possible cases that may occur in this scenario.

```
SELECT 
u.userID, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, 
SUM(1 - ((!(answer.a = question.a)) + (!(answer.b = question.b)) + (!(answer.c = question.c)) + (!(answer.d = question.d))) * 0.25) AS Score 
FROM answer 
INNER JOIN 
user u ON answer.userID = u.userID 
INNER JOIN 
question ON answer.questionID = question.questionID 
GROUP BY answer.userID
```